# Not able to run python file via system() command in a shared object file

Tags: c, linux, pam, .so, jpype

(Find the code attached below) I am trying to change the authentication mechanism of SSH in Ubuntu systems to use a zero-knowledge proof based authentication instead of normal username-password. I am trying to build upon the work provided in [this git repo](https://github.com/vonderhaar/6857-PasswordManager) and mitigate some of its vulnerabilities. It uses a shared object file called 'pam_schnorr.so' in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security which returns PAM_SUCCESS or PAM_IGNORE to the ssh process and grants authentication accordingly.

pam_schnorr.so runs a python3 file 'attempt.py' using system() command. attempt.py in turn runs some java code(which writes y/n into output.txt after some computation) using jpype. **The problem I am facing is that system() command is not able to run attempt.py successfully as the WEXITSTATUS returned is 1**. These are some combinations I've tried till now -

1. I am able to successfully run the attempt.py file using system() command in test.c which is present in the same folder as pam_schnorr.so
2. I am able to successfully run attempt.py via terminal
3. I am able to run a simple python file test.py via system() command in pam_schnorr.so
4. I am able to run attempt.py via system() in pam_schnorr.so if i comment out the import jpype and other jpype related statements

Therefore I have come to the conclusion that **the problem maybe with trying to run jpype statements in attempt.py when being run via system() in a .so file**.

The commands I've used to generate pam_schnorr.so from pam_schnorr.c are -

$sudo gcc -c -fPIC pam_schnorr.c -o new_pam_schnorr.o

$sudo gcc new_pam_schnorr.o -shared -o pam_schnorr.so

I am not sure what the problem is exactly, but running attempt.py from pam_schnorr.so is essential for the authentication process. Any help regarding this is appreciated

attempt.py

```
import jpype
import sys
import traceback

def main(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i):
    classpath = "-Djava.class.path=%s" % "/home/madhav/Downloads/6857-PasswordManager/out/production/6.857_ZKPassword/"
    jpype.startJVM("/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so", classpath)
    Main = jpype.JPackage("sixeightfiveseven").Main
    Main.main([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i])
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # expect 9 arguments
    a = sys.argv[1]
    b = sys.argv[2]
    c = sys.argv[3]
    d = sys.argv[4]
    e = sys.argv[5]
    f = sys.argv[6]
    g = sys.argv[7]
    h = sys.argv[8]
    i = sys.argv[9]
    main(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
```

test.c   // WEXITSTATUS returned is 0 (success)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void main(){
    FILE *f = fopen("/home/madhav/Desktop/debug.txt", "w+");
    int status = system("sudo python3 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/attempt.py"); //providing the reqd arguments for attempt.py
    fprintf(f, "\nSTATUS: %d", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    if (status != 0) {
      fprintf(f, "failed :(\n");
    }
    else{
        fprintf(f, "success :)\n"); 
    }
    fclose(f); 
}
```

test.py

```
def func():
    f = open("/home/madhav/Desktop/demofile.txt", "a")
    f.write("Now the file has more content!")
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func()
```

pam_schnorr.c (system call in pam_sm_athenticate function)

```
/* Define which PAM interfaces we provide */
  #define PAM_SM_ACCOUNT
  #define PAM_SM_AUTH
  #define PAM_SM_PASSWORD
  #define PAM_SM_SESSION

#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* Include PAM headers */
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <security/pam_ext.h>
#include <security/_pam_macros.h>
#include <security/pam_modutil.h>

  /* PAM entry point for session creation */
  int pam_sm_open_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
          return(PAM_IGNORE);
  }

  /* PAM entry point for session cleanup */
  int pam_sm_close_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
          return(PAM_IGNORE);
  }

  /* PAM entry point for accounting */
  int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
          return(PAM_IGNORE);
  }

  /* PAM entry point for authentication verification */
  int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    int retval; 
    const char *p;
    retval = pam_get_authtok(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, &p , NULL);

    // open a file to help debug
    FILE *f = fopen("/home/sylvielee/Desktop/debug_log.txt", "w");
    
    // Expect a string containing GP_x,GP_y,PK_x,PK_y,V_x,V_Y,r,n,userID in that order
    int num_vars = 9;
    int pv_index = 0;
    char *packet_vars[num_vars];
    const char *delimiter = ",";

    char *saveptr;
    char *var = strtok_r(p, delimiter, &saveptr);
    if (!var) {
      fprintf(f, "incorrect input");
      fclose(f); 
      return(PAM_IGNORE); 
    }
    packet_vars[pv_index++] = var;

    while (pv_index < num_vars) {
      var = strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &saveptr);
      fprintf(f, "\npv index is %d\n", pv_index);
      fprintf(f, "var is %s\n", var);
      if (!var) {
    fprintf(f, "broke out"); 
    break; 
      }
      packet_vars[pv_index++] = var;
    }
    
    if (pv_index != num_vars) {
      // didn't get all the desired variables
      fclose(f); 
      return(PAM_IGNORE); 
    }

    // call python script to check with verifier
    char script_call[80];
    sprintf(script_call, "python3 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/attempt.py %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",
        packet_vars[0], packet_vars[1], packet_vars[2], packet_vars[3], packet_vars[4],
        packet_vars[5], packet_vars[6], packet_vars[7], packet_vars[8]);
    puts(script_call);
    fprintf(f, "\n%s", script_call); 

    // check success of script call and log
    int status = system(script_call); 
    fprintf(f, "\nSTATUS: %d", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    if (status != 0) {
      fprintf(f, "failed :("); 
      fclose(f); 
      return(PAM_IGNORE); 
    }

    // read the verifier result
    char *verifier_fp = "/home/sylvielee/Desktop/out.txt";
    FILE *verifier_output = fopen(verifier_fp, "r");
    int good = 0;    
    if (fgetc(verifier_output) == 121) { // ASCII for y
      good = 1; 
    }
    fprintf(f, "\nOutput is %d\n", good);
    
    // return success of failure based on verifier result
    fclose(f);
    fclose(verifier_output);
    if (good == 1) {
      return(PAM_SUCCESS); 
    }
    return(PAM_IGNORE);
  }

  /*
     PAM entry point for setting user credentials (that is, to actually
     establish the authenticated user's credentials to the service provider)
   */
  int pam_sm_setcred(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
          return(PAM_IGNORE);
  }

  /* PAM entry point for authentication token (password) changes */
  int pam_sm_chauthtok(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
          return(PAM_IGNORE);
  }
```

Comment: What is the value of `PATH` when calling the pam-module? But, creating a command line to call a python script with `sprintf` and calling it with `system` !? And doing all that in a pam module for ssh?!! I really hope that you  are trying to creating a honneypot...

Comment: @HAL9000 the value of PATH in pam_schnorr.c was "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin" whereas the value of PATH in test.c (which was able to run attempt.py successfully) was "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin". I tried to change path in pam_schnorr.c using setenv but even after that the error still persists. Is there anything else I should be changing?

Comment: @HAL9000 As far as the flow of code and running python from system() is concerned, I am just trying to reproduce the result from the github for now, I am planning to change the structure to run the java files from pam_schnorr directly using JNI later on but I just wanted to get it working with the original github code once.

Comment: Are you sure `script_call` is large enough to hold the result of `sprintf`?  Does any of `packet_vars[i]` contain any "funny" characters? Remember that the string passed to `system` gets interpreted as a command line by the shell. What is the value of `SHELL`? Never use `system`. If an a attacker can trick you into having a `;` or any other funny character in the command string, you have a compromised system. Use `fork`/`exec` and be vigilant of what executable you are calling.